# Delete key issue in bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I have a directive that uses the following code

```
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        var parent = $(element).parent();
        var dtp = parent.datetimepicker({
            format: "MM/DD/YYYY",
            showTodayButton: true,
            defaultDate: attrs.minDate,
            minDate: attrs.minDate
        });

        dtp.on("keydown"), function (e) {
              if (e.switch === 46) {
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
        });

        dtp.on("dp.change", function (e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(moment(e.date).format("LL"));
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
};
```

it doesn't work, however, if I change it to other keys like space, or alphanumeric keys, the e.preventDefault() executes.

The reason I need to do this is that delete doesn't remove the value in my ngModel, so this will be my workaround. If I use backspace, it works perfectly. Any known issues about the delete key?

Comment: Why do you not use a library like Boostrap UI (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to avoid such problems in the first place? This library includes also the typical bootstrap datetime picker.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is already in production use and cannot be changed easily. However, i'll try your suggestion if we can modify everything. Anyway, any idea why the delete key doesn't capture in keydown event ?

Comment: Maybe a special behavior of the datetimepicker. Can you provide a link to the datetimepicker library?